# IFileOpenDialog buttons don't work when used with another Dialog open

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

My application consists of a predefined dialog and a couple of buttons. One of the buttons is supposed to open folder picker dialog, so I used IFileOpenDialog. However, when this dialog is opened after my main dialog is created, "Select Folder", "Cancel" and "X" buttons don't work, as if nobody is processing the click event (navigation through file system still works).

Minimal reproducible example (compile with UNICODE):

Resource.rc

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "winres.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (United States) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""winres.h""\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED

#endif    // English (United States) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_LTH)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_DIALOG1 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 191, 52
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    PUSHBUTTON      "Browse...",IDC_BUTTON_BROWSE,71,19,50,14
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// DESIGNINFO
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO
BEGIN
    IDD_DIALOG1, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 184
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 45
    END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
//

IDD_DIALOG1 AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT
BEGIN
    0
END

#endif
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

Program.cpp

```
#include <assert.h>

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define NOMINMAX
#include <windows.h>

#include <shobjidl_core.h>
#include <wrl.h>

#include "resource.h"

static void PickDirectory(HWND hwnd)
{
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IFileDialog> folderPicker;
    auto hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&folderPicker));
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    DWORD pickerOptions;
    hr = folderPicker->GetOptions(&pickerOptions);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    hr = folderPicker->SetOptions(pickerOptions | FOS_PICKFOLDERS);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    if (SUCCEEDED(folderPicker->Show(hwnd)))
    {
        Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IShellItem> folderShellItem;
        hr = folderPicker->GetResult(&folderShellItem);
        assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

        PWSTR folderPath = nullptr;
        hr = folderShellItem->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &folderPath);
        assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

        OutputDebugStringW(L"Picked folder: ");
        OutputDebugStringW(folderPath);
        OutputDebugStringW(L"\r\n");

        CoTaskMemFree(folderPath);
    }

    return;
}

static LRESULT WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDC_BUTTON_BROWSE && HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED)
        {
            PickDirectory(hwnd); // <------- freezes!
            return 0;
        }

        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int CALLBACK wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, LPWSTR, int nCmdShow)
{
    auto hr = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    PickDirectory(nullptr); // <------- works!

    auto hwnd = CreateDialogParamW(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), nullptr, WndProc, 0);
    assert(hwnd != nullptr);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    PickDirectory(nullptr); // <------- freezes!

    for (;;)
    {
        MSG msg;
        auto getMessageResult = GetMessageW(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0);

        if (getMessageResult == 0 || getMessageResult == -1)
            break;

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the folder picker works before I create the main application dialog. After creating it, it doesn't anymore.

Is there some secret sauce you have to use when opening IFileOpenDialog when using other dialogs?

Comment: `CreateDialogParam` expects a [dialog procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nc-winuser-dlgproc), not a window procedure. Among other things, `DialogProc` should not call `DefWindowProc`, and should return `TRUE` if it processed the message (and `FALSE` if it should be sent for default processing).

Comment: :facepalm: I can't believe I made this mistake. Everything works now. Please repost this as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Igor Tandetnik pointed out, `CreateDialogParam` takes `DialogProc` rather than `WndProc`. Although they both have the same signatures (so you won't see a compiler error), their return value differs: `DialogProc` does not call `DefWindowProc`.

Fixing that made the file open picker work once again.